# Typescript error cannot invoke an object which is possibly undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

React callback onClick Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Below is my parent component which handles the `state` of the app.

```
 function App() {   
    const [bandData, setBandData] = useState<any | undefined>(undefined);
    return(
      <> 
          <Bands bands={bands} onBandClick={band => setBandData(band)} />
          <Modal bandData={bandData} />
      </>
    )
}
```

Next is my component which passes the state back up the tree. However, I am getting the following typescript error:

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

```
type Props = {
   bands: any[];
   onBandClick: (arg: any) => void;
}

function Bands({bands, onBandClick}: Props) {
   return(
     <div>
       {bands.map(band => {
         // the error is coming from onBandClick
         // No error if I change it to onBandClick={onBandClick}
         <Band name={band.name} onBandClick={band => onBandClick(band)} />
       })
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: promise that `bands` is not undefined/null `bands!.map` therefore each `band` is not undefined/null too.  maybe even  `band! => ` is needed

Comment: Can you include the implementation of `Band`?